# TI-Basic Parenthesis Syntax

Tags: ti-basic

I found a program I made on my calculator many years ago, and I am having trouble understanding what the line

```
Z-1(Z=0 → Z
```

does in it. I tried just changing it to

```
Z-1 → Z
```

but that ended up breaking it. Here is an excerpt, any information would be helpful!

```
ClrHome
Prompt A,B,C
A*C → D
B-1 → Z
Z-1(Z=0 → Z
D/Z → F
F+Z → G
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty common for complex variable trickery without if statements and such. This is pretty much saying if Z=0, subtract 1 from Z. If Z isn't 0, Z=0 becomes 0, and Z-1(0 (order of operations is multiply first) is just Z-0, which will leave the variable unchanged. In normal code it would be like:

```
If not(Z
Z-1->Z
```

Just another thing to point out, `If not(Z[newline]` and `(Z=0` have the same amount of tokens, which means you should do `(not(Z` instead to save space. Never in ti basic should you really have a =0 because that is 2 tokens for something not( can do in one.